# Simplifying SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

so I have a statement I believe should work... However it feels pretty suboptimal and I can't for the life of me figure out how to optimise it.

I have the following tables:

- Transactions

  - [Id] is `PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY`
  - [Hash] has a `UNIQUE` constraint
  - [BlockNumber] has an Index
- Transfers

  - [Id] is `PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY`
  - [TransactionId] is a Foreign Key referencing [Transactions].[Id]
- TokenPrices

  - [Id] is `PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY`
- TokenPriceAttempts

  - [Id] is `PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY`
  - [TransferId] is a Foreign Key referencing [Transfers].[Id]

What I want to do, is select all the transfers, with a few bits of data from their related transaction (one transaction to many transfers), where I don't currently have a price stored in TokenPrices related to that transfer.

In the first part of the query, I am getting a list of all the transfers, and calculating the DIFF between the nearest found token price. If one isn't found, this is null (what I ultimately want to select). I am allowing 3 hours either side of the transaction timestamp - if nothing is found within that timespan, it will be null.

Secondly, I am selecting from this set, ensuring first that diff is null as this means the price is missing, and finally that token price attempts either doesn't have an entry for attempting to get a price, or if it does than it has fewer than 5 attempts listed and the last attempt was more than a week ago.

The way I have laid this out results in essentially 3 of the same / similar SELECT statements within the WHERE clause, which feels hugely suboptimal...

How could I improve this approach?

```
        WITH [transferDateDiff] AS 
        (
            SELECT
                [t1].[Id],
                [t1].[TransactionId],
                [t1].[From],
                [t1].[To],
                [t1].[Value],
                [t1].[Type],
                [t1].[ContractAddress],
                [t1].[TokenId],
                [t2].[Hash],
                [t2].[Timestamp],
                ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, [tp].[Timestamp], [t2].[Timestamp])) AS diff 
            FROM
                [dbo].[Transfers] AS [t1]
                LEFT JOIN
                    [dbo].[Transactions] AS [t2] 
                    ON [t1].[TransactionId] = [t2].[Id]
                LEFT JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT
                            * 
                        FROM
                            [dbo].[TokenPrices]
                    )
                    AS [tp] 
                    ON [tp].[ContractAddress] = [t1].[ContractAddress]
                    AND [tp].[Timestamp] >= DATEADD(HOUR, - 3, [t2].[Timestamp]) 
                    AND [tp].[Timestamp] <= DATEADD(HOUR, 3, [t2].[Timestamp]) 
            WHERE
                [t1].[Type] < 2
        )


        SELECT
            [tdd].[Id],
            [tdd].[TransactionId],
            [tdd].[From],
            [tdd].[To],
            [tdd].[Value],
            [tdd].[Type],
            [tdd].[ContractAddress],
            [tdd].[TokenId],
            [tdd].[Hash],
            [tdd].[Timestamp]
        FROM
            [transferDateDiff] AS tdd
        WHERE
            [tdd].[diff] IS NULL AND
            (
                (
                    SELECT
                        COUNT(*)
                    FROM
                        [dbo].[TokenPriceAttempts] tpa
                    WHERE
                        [tpa].[TransferId] = [tdd].[Id]
                )
                = 0 OR
                (
                    (
                        SELECT
                            COUNT(*)
                        FROM
                            [dbo].[TokenPriceAttempts] tpa
                        WHERE
                            [tpa].[TransferId] = [tdd].[Id]
                    )
                    < 5 AND
                    (
                        DATEDIFF(DAY,
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    MAX([tpa].[Created])
                                FROM
                                    [dbo].[TokenPriceAttempts] tpa
                                WHERE
                                    [tpa].[TransferId] = [tdd].[Id]
                            ),
                            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                        ) >= 7
                    )
                )
            )
```

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: What does *improve* mean - does the query return incorrect results or is there a performance issue? If the latter, add details of the tables involved, indexes/keys/constraints and [Paste the actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: @Stu Have added the tag and its a question of performance. I have provided indexes etc above.

Comment: We can't see any details of data types or indexed columns, script the objects and include the `create` statements; And again, [Paste the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt to help simplify. I stripped out all the [brackets] that really are not required unless you are running into something like a reserved keyword, or columns with spaces in their name (bad to begin with).

Anyhow, your main query had 3 instances of a select per ID.  To eliminate that, I did a LEFT JOIN to a subquery that pulls all transfers of type < 2 AND JOINS to the price attempts ONCE.  This way, the result will have already pre-aggregated the count(*) and Max(Created) done ONCE for the same basis of transfers in question with your WITH CTE declaration.  So you dont have to keep running the 3 queries each time, and you dont have to query the entire table of ALL transfers, just those with same underlying type < 2 condition. The result subquery alias "PQ" (preQuery)

This now simplifies the readability of the outer WHERE clause from the redundant counts per Id.

```
WITH transferDateDiff AS 
(
SELECT
        t1.Id,
        t1.TransactionId,
        t1.From,
        t1.To,
        t1.Value,
        t1.Type,
        t1.ContractAddress,
        t1.TokenId,
        t2.Hash,
        t2.Timestamp,
        ABS( DATEDIFF( SECOND, tp.Timestamp, t2.Timestamp )) AS diff 
    FROM
        dbo.Transfers t1
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Transactions t2
                ON t1.TransactionId = t2.Id
                LEFT JOIN dbo.TokenPrices tp
                    ON t1.ContractAddress = tp.ContractAddress
                    AND tp.Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR, - 3, t2.Timestamp)
                    AND tp.Timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR, 3, t2.Timestamp)
    WHERE
        t1.Type < 2
)


SELECT
        tdd.Id,
        tdd.TransactionId,
        tdd.From,
        tdd.To,
        tdd.Value,
        tdd.Type,
        tdd.ContractAddress,
        tdd.TokenId,
        tdd.Hash,
        tdd.Timestamp
    FROM
        transferDateDiff tdd
            LEFT JOIN
            ( SELECT
                    t1.Id,
                    COUNT(*) Attempts,
                    MAX(tpa.Created) MaxCreated
                FROM
                    dbo.Transfers t1
                        JOIN dbo.TokenPriceAttempts tpa
                            on t1.Id = tpa.TransferId
                WHERE
                    t1.Type < 2
                GROUP BY
                    t1.Id ) PQ
                on tdd.Id = PQ.Id
    WHERE
            tdd.diff IS NULL 
        AND (   PQ.Attempts IS NULL
            OR PQ.Attempts = 0
            OR (    PQ.Attempts < 5
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, PQ.MaxCreated, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) >= 7
                )
            )
```

**REVISED to remove the WITH CTE into a single query**

```
SELECT
        t1.Id,
        t1.TransactionId,
        t1.From,
        t1.To,
        t1.Value,
        t1.Type,
        t1.ContractAddress,
        t1.TokenId,
        t2.Hash,
        t2.Timestamp
    FROM
        -- Now, this pre-query is left-joined to token price attempts
        -- so ALL Transfers of type < 2 are considered
        ( SELECT
                t1.Id,
                coalesce( COUNT(*), 0 ) Attempts,
                MAX(tpa.Created) MaxCreated
            FROM
                dbo.Transfers t1
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.TokenPriceAttempts tpa
                        on t1.Id = tpa.TransferId
            WHERE
                t1.Type < 2
            GROUP BY
                t1.Id ) PQ
            -- Now, we can just directly join to transfers for the rest
            JOIN dbo.Transfers t1
                on PQ.Id = t1.Id
                -- and the rest from the WITH CTE construct
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Transactions t2
                    ON t1.TransactionId = t2.Id
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.TokenPrices tp
                        ON t1.ContractAddress = tp.ContractAddress
                        AND tp.Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR, - 3, t2.Timestamp)
                        AND tp.Timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR, 3, t2.Timestamp)
    WHERE
            ABS( DATEDIFF( SECOND, tp.Timestamp, t2.Timestamp )) IS NULL
        AND (   PQ.Attempts = 0
            OR (    PQ.Attempts < 5
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, PQ.MaxCreated, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) >= 7 )
            )
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great - got rid of the duplicated parts I was worried about.
Do you think there is a way to combine the transferDateDiff part into the main SELECT statement, and if so, would that be necessarily better, or is it fine keeping it as is?
Thanks.

Comment: @pingu2k4, revised and added additional version without the WITH CTE construct.  Try to confirm first though.

Comment: Apologies for delay, but the revision is great, thanks @drapp. I've had life take over for a while and only just got back to things. Switched out my previous for the updated version you posted and its not only cleaner visually, but much more performant. With more data in my database, my old query was taking ~ 3 seconds, which would surely have only gotten worse over time. This new query is near instant, so a massive lifesaver. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are doing this:

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        [dbo].[TokenPrices]
)
AS [tp] 
ON [tp].[ContractAddress] = [t1].[ContractAddress]
AND [tp].[Timestamp] >= DATEADD(HOUR, - 3, [t2].[Timestamp]) 
AND [tp].[Timestamp] <= DATEADD(HOUR, 3, [t2].[Timestamp])
```

Isn't this a

```
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TokenPrices] as TP ...
```

This:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    [dbo].[TokenPriceAttempts] tpa
WHERE
    [tpa].[TransferId] = [tdd].[Id]
```

could be another CTE instead of being a sub...
In fact any of your sub queries could be CTE's, that's part of a CTE is making things easier to read.

```
,TPA
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[TokenPriceAttempts] tpa
    WHERE [tpa].[TransferId] = [tdd].[Id]
)
```

Comment: The first point is definitely an issue - It was left after I was attempting to do other stuff before and totally forgot to revert that part of what I had altered. Thanks.
As for the other parts you mention, I'm not sure how I could change anything based on what you mention sorry?

Comment: You can have as many CTE's as you would like in your query. Anything that is a nested correlated query could be pulled out as a separate cte instead of nesting.